# How can I apply a material on a product packaging?

Tags: texturing, materials

[image]

[image]

[image]

So the first image is the material I'm trying to apply, and the second image is what I currently have. It's been rendered in cycles. As you can see, the material is quite flat and plain, and doesn't have that realistic texture to it. The last image is the nodes applied to the box. So how do I go about applying that texture to my current packaging design?

Comment: Hello so how did you get the first material you show? You need to plug it into a Bump node that you plug into the Normal input of your Principled BSDF

Comment: I got the material from blenderkit. Once I apply the material, my current design disappears, so I'm unsure how to do have the design and material at the same time

Comment: please pack the images (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file?

Comment: I've done that, but how do I sent it through here?

Comment: you need to copy paste the link here